# Cannot play video on videoview android with url from facebook

Tags: java, android

[photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6lTe.jpg)
when i'm adding videoview with url from facebook/youtube application shows "Cannot play this video" heres my code

```
 VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoPlay ) ;
    String url  = getIntent().getStringExtra("url") ;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaZ3PoWIRvg");
    vv.setVideoURI(uri);
    vv.start();
```

Comment: Have you given *Internet Permission* inside *Android Manifest* file ?

Comment: yes it's already defined

Comment: Could you show *XML layout* and *Full Activity code* here ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context="com.example.badr.upcity.PlayVid">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoPlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"" />

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context="com.example.badr.upcity.PlayVid">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoPlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Comment: Your code is correct may be some issue with youtube link i tried another link with your code it's working.

Comment: thanks i  wil try another link

Comment: @NikunjPatel i tried with another link but it's the same issue

Comment: You can take a sample video link from here http://abhiandroid.com/ui/videoview

If you want to play youtube video u must be integrate youtube SDK

Comment: thanks i tried with link you give it to me and it worked